# Combining Select Statements

Tags: sql, select

I have three select statements that provide the number of Members that attend particular events - Healthcare, Religious and Sport - in addition to the average "score" for each event and a count for each.

The count will differ for each event.

Individually each query works, but I want to combine them into one query.

How do I do that?

```
 (select sum(case when Healthcare ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_never],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_not often],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_average],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_often],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_very often]
 ,avg(Cast(Healthcare as float)) as Average
 ,count(Healthcare) as N_Healthcare
 from Member 
 where Healthcare > '0' )


 (select
  sum(case when Religious ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_never],
  sum(case when Religious ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_not often],
  sum(case when Religious ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_average],
  sum(case when Religious ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_often],
  sum(case when Religious ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_very often],
  Avg(cast(Religious as float)) as Average
  ,count(Religious) as N_Religious
  from Member 
  where Religious > '0' )


 (select
 sum(case when Sport ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_never],
 sum(case when Sport ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_not often],
 sum(case when Sport ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_average],
 sum(case when Sport ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_often],
 sum(case when Sport ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_very often],
 Avg(cast(Sport as float)) as Average
 ,count(Sport) as N_Sport
 from Member 
 where Sport > '0' )
```

Comment: What columns would you like to get from the combined query?

Comment: What is your goal in combining the statements? What have you tried so far?

Comment: My goal is to have a value for each of the columns and the appropriate count. The problem I've had is in the Where statement... I'll post what I've tried below.

Comment: To expand on the above comments, please consider explicit expected output of the requested changes.  It'll make the answers much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select 
sum(case when Healthcare ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_never],
sum(case when Healthcare ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_not often],
sum(case when Healthcare ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_average],
sum(case when Healthcare ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_often],
sum(case when Healthcare ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_very often],
avg(Cast((case when Healthcare > 0 Then Healthcare Else Null end) as float)) as Healthcare_Average,
count(case when Healthcare > 0 Then Healthcare Else Null end) as N_Healthcare,

sum(case when Religious ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_never],
sum(case when Religious ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_not often],
sum(case when Religious ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_average],
sum(case when Religious ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_often],
sum(case when Religious ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_very often],
Avg(cast((case when Religious > 0 Then Religious Else Null end) as float)) as Religious_Average,
count(case when Religious > 0 Then Religious Else Null end) as N_Religious,

sum(case when Sport ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_never],
sum(case when Sport ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_not often],
sum(case when Sport ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_average],
sum(case when Sport ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_often],
sum(case when Sport ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_very often],
Avg(cast((case when Sport > 0 Then Sport Else Null end) as float)) as Sport_Average,
count(case when Sport > 0 Then Sport Else Null end) as N_Sport

from Member
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put UNION ALL between the SELECT statements.  But you'll probably want to add another column to indicate which table it came from.  And the column headers need to be the same.  For example:

```
 select 'Healthcare' as source
, sum(case when Healthcare ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [never], 
 sum(case when Healthcare ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [not often], 
 sum(case when Healthcare ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [average], 
 sum(case when Healthcare ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [often], 
 sum(case when Healthcare ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [very often] 
 ,avg(Cast(Healthcare as float)) as Average 
 ,count(Healthcare) as N_Healthcare 
 from Member  
 where Healthcare > '0' 
UNION ALL
```

etc.

Comment: The column headers do not need to be the same.  The column names are taken from the first subquery, and the names in subsequent subqueries are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the where statement provides an incorrect count for each event.
The Healthcare count should be 54, Sport 54 and Other 13
Instead the count of all is 55.

```
 select 
 sum(case when Healthcare ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_never],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_not often],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_average],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_often],
 sum(case when Healthcare ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Healthcare_very often],
 avg(Cast(Healthcare as float)) as Average,
 count(Healthcare) as N_Healthcare,

 sum(case when Religious ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_never],
 sum(case when Religious ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_not often],
 sum(case when Religious ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_average],
 sum(case when Religious ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_often],
 sum(case when Religious ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Religious_very often],
 Avg(cast(Religious as float)) as Average,
 count(Religious) as N_Religious,

 sum(case when Sport ='1' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_never],
 sum(case when Sport ='2' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_not often],
 sum(case when Sport ='3' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_average],
 sum(case when Sport ='4' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_often],
 sum(case when Sport ='5' then 1 else 0 end)  as [Sport_very often],
 Avg(cast(Sport as float)) as Average,
 count(Sport) as N_Sport
 from contacts_cstm 
 where Sport > '0' or Religious > '0' or Healthcare >'0'
```

Comment: this wont return correct data when you use `OR` condition like above.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't return the correct data. Your previous example did. Thank you!